# Changing permissions on all files and folders in a given folder

Tags: windows-7

I've recently reinstalled Windows 7, and all the files on the backup hard disk I use are exclusively set to ownership on my previous admin account. How this occurred, I have no idea, but now I can't access my own files. Using my new admin account, I set the ownership to the new account and then set myself to full permissions. But when I changed the settings on a folder, *some* of the contents recursively updated but others did not- I have to change every one of these files and folders manually, of which there are a great many. I tried setting myself to act as part of the operating system in the Local Security Policy, but again, this has only worked to grant access to *some* of the files. There are still many more that I can't access.

I need to wipe all trace of the previous administrator account from all files and folders on the hard drive and grant myself all permissions.

Any suggestions as to how I can eliminate this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you mount your drive in Linux, the permissions will be pretty much ignored *if the files are not encrypted*:

1. Boot from a live CD
2. Copy files to a location that doesn't understand NTFS permissions, e.g., a FAT32 partition or USB stick
3. Copy them back to a new location on the original NTFS partition that has its file permission set properly
4. Boot back into Windows.

Any [live CD](http://livecdlist.com/) that can mount NTFS will do here. Ubuntu works from my experience.

My solution is a bit blunt, I'd be curious to see a batch file or script that repeatedly calls `icacls` and/or `takeown`.

Comment: Turns out that there's a button in Windows which *does* take ownership recursively in all conditions. Thanks for the answer, but it's not what I ultimately went with.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.